# Can't download blobs inside a folder using Node.js SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to download some blobs in a blob container in azure.

I have success when the file its on the root container, but not when is inside a folder.

```
const folder = 'AZURE_FOLDER';

const filesToDownload =  [ 'icon.ico', 'images/cover.jpg', 'images/htmlstructure.png' ]

filesToDownload.forEach(blob => {
      service.download(containerName, blob, `${folder}/${blob}`)
});
```

Running this code, the downloaded file is 'icon.ico', but all others I receive this error:

> error : { Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'AZURE_FOLDER/images/cover.jpg'
>
> error : { Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'AZURE_FOLDER/images/htmlstructure.png'

#### My listBlobs response:

```
BlobResult {
  name: 'images/cover.jpg',
  creationTime: 'Wed, 03 Apr 2019 17:14:03 GMT',
  lastModified: 'Wed, 03 Apr 2019 17:14:03 GMT',
  etag: '0x8D6B857C5B2B355',
  contentLength: '299040',
  contentSettings: 
   { contentType: 'image/jpeg',
     contentEncoding: '',
     contentLanguage: '',
     contentMD5: 'JqJRnPltEsAhar+YfKgEtQ==',
     cacheControl: '',
     contentDisposition: '' },
  blobType: 'BlockBlob',
  accessTier: 'Hot',
  accessTierInferred: true,
  lease: { status: 'unlocked', state: 'available' },
  serverEncrypted: 'true' }
BlobResult {
  name: 'images/htmlstructure.png',
  creationTime: 'Wed, 03 Apr 2019 17:14:02 GMT',
  lastModified: 'Wed, 03 Apr 2019 17:14:02 GMT',
  etag: '0x8D6B857C4ECA732',
  contentLength: '65835',
  contentSettings: 
   { contentType: 'image/png',
     contentEncoding: '',
     contentLanguage: '',
     contentMD5: 'uHsFKqK9csssX0XYt86dlA==',
     cacheControl: '',
     contentDisposition: '' },
  blobType: 'BlockBlob',
  accessTier: 'Hot',
  accessTierInferred: true,
  lease: { status: 'unlocked', state: 'available' },
  serverEncrypted: 'true' }
BlobResult {
  name: 'user.ico',
  creationTime: 'Wed, 03 Apr 2019 16:58:24 GMT',
  lastModified: 'Wed, 03 Apr 2019 16:58:33 GMT',
  etag: '0x8D6B8559B5CC9C8',
  contentLength: '179677',
  contentSettings: 
   { contentType: 'image/x-icon',
     contentEncoding: '',
     contentLanguage: '',
     contentMD5: 'sHZ3nvd9fyX09EkqQvDvLQ==',
     cacheControl: '',
     contentDisposition: '' },
  blobType: 'BlockBlob',
  accessTier: 'Hot',
  accessTierInferred: true,
  lease: { status: 'unlocked', state: 'available' },
  serverEncrypted: 'true' }
```

Comment: maybe you should use azure sdk for nodejs

Comment: I'm already using, thks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the `AZURE_FOLDER/images` directory exist? If not, you will need to create it using the `fs` module beforehand.

Comment: I create the images folder and it worth!

Comment: glad it worked! Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you ;)